# How can I force NgbCarousel to loop to first after I goes to last picture of slideshow

Tags: angular, carousel, slideshow, ng-bootstrap

How can I force NgbCarousel to loop to first picture after It goes to last picture of slideshow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what is exactly being asked, but if you are wanting the NgbCarousel to be able to navigate to the **first** slide/image when on the **last** either by clicking on the next arrow or on it's own when an interval is set, you'd need to have property `wrap` set to true. From the documentation:

> `wrap` Type: boolean Default value: true — initialized from NgbCarouselConfig
>   service Whether can wrap from the last to the first slide.

This can be set on either the the tag like `<ngb-carousel wrap="true">` or in a global config using `NgbCarouselConfig`. It defaults to true.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCX9p0nRFd92OhhfyNJb?p=preview) demonstrating it in action.

Hopefully that helps!